# How to send client key and secret for authentication in react native

Tags: react-native

I am making an react native android application in which in need to send client key and client secret to server.

```
    const a = "ck_a332f4d89de6eed37b108f9eda13cfa1e71ce438";
    const b = "cs_1c700d679d9613f507479325c1f53be4d3eac858";
    const basicToken= base64.encode(a+ ':' +b);

   componentDidMount(){
          axios.get('http://link.com', {
                   method: 'GET',

              headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',


                'Authorization': `Basic ${basicToken}` ,
                //'consumer_key': "ck_a332f4d89de6eed37b108f9eda13cfa1e71ce438", 
                //'consumer_secret':"cs_1c700d679d9613f507479325c1f53be4d3eac858",

              },



            }).then((response) => response.json())
                  .then((responseJson) => {

                       ToastAndroid.show(JSON.stringify(responseJson),ToastAndroid.LONG)


                  }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                  });
  }
```

I have tried using both above code but it gives me 401 error.What i am doing wrong here? How can i send client key and secret to server using axios/fetch api

Answer (score 1):

As you have specified you are receiving an HTTP status code of  401. This implies you are unauthorized. You must log in with a valid user ID and password. Please cross check your token value.

Comment: i think problem is 'Authorization': `Basic ${basicToken}` , this line as i  have to do autho v1 but i have used basic authentication

Comment: Where do you think the problem persists?

Comment: 'Authorization': Basic ${basicToken} .as i have to do autho v1 but i have used basic authentication

Comment: try using `token ${basicToken}`

Comment: did you cross check your token value?

Comment: Is it really a 'GET' method?

Comment: You get a token when you log in with valid credential, save it using AsynStorage and reuse the same token while posting your secret values.

Comment: How to get tokens then ? In wordpress api i only got client key and secret

Comment: Is it okay for you to tell me about the API? I will test it on postman provide you info on how to tackle the problem.